# How to develop data driven framework using Selenium with C#? Please provide example

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, test-automation-framework, data-driven

How we can develop data driven framework using Selenium with C# to test the web applications? In your response can you please provide an example?

Comment: This is far too broad for this site: could you give us more information please: what have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I didn't tried anything. Just I want to learn Data driven framework to automate web applications.               Example I have to automate Gmail register page using selenium with c#. So, I have prepared all required data (last name, first name, ph number, password, confirm password) in a Excel sheet. Then I have retrieve that data from Excel sheet and enter all that retrieved data in Gmail registration page with respect to specified text boxes in registration page.

Please help me to develop script using selenium with c#.

Answer (score 2):

You develop it just like anything else you would program. Learn the different parts and combine them together.

- Learn C#: http://www.learncs.org/
- Learn how to read data from Excel with C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp
- Learn how to drive a test with Selenium in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334065/how-do-i-use-selenium-in-c

Now when you are combining and implementing it if you get stuck you can ask specific questions to get help with. Although searching the internet might also help first.

Microsoft also has its own implementation of data-driven tests:

> Using the Microsoft unit test framework for managed code, you can set
>   up a unit test method to retrieve values used in the test method from
>   a data source. The method is run successively for each row in the data
>   source, which makes it easy to test a variety of input by using a
>   single method.
>
> read more and examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx

Other alternatives:

- FitNesse: https://fitsharp.github.io/

Comment: Instead of parsing Excel, I'm a fan of FitNesse/fitSharp. Very flexible with many already existing table implementations

Comment: NIce, didnt know they had a c# implementation. Added it :)